# django urls named groups

Tags: python, django, url

I want to match any url with a numeric id (various length) at the end and pass that id to a view function.
My urls are in this form:

```
/event/dash-separated-strings-2014-12-16-342614/
```

The id is 342614. The content before the date is also various.

Here is my url config:

```
 url(r'^event/(*.-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-)(?P<event_id>\d*)/$', view_event , name='my_view_event')
```

The problem is that the full url is passed to my view function. What i want is the named group only. What is wrong with my config?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
url(r'^event/[\w\-]+-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-(?P<event_id>\d+)/$', view_event , name='my_view_event')
```

Comment: Same problem with that.